# Remove child array from array where child item is the last of that item

Tags: php, arrays, loops

My brain is broken. Here's the concept:

```
$a = array('please', 2);
$s = array('help', 3);
$d = array('me', 1);
$f = array('!', 3);
$g = array('asdf', 1);

$myArray = array($a, $s, $d, $f, $g);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($myArray); $i++) {
    // code here
}
```

Code should contain logic that removes indexes 0, 3, and 4 from myArray because they contain the last value of their kinds (last 2, 3, and 1 respectively) at position $myArray[$i][1].

--EDIT:
Adapted suggestions from comments to get this:

```
$a = array('please', 2);
$s = array('help', 3);
$d = array('me', 1);
$f = array('!', 3);
$g = array('asdf', 1);

$myArray = array($a, $s, $d, $f, $g);

$used = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($myArray); $i++) {
    $used[$myArray[$i][1]] = $i;
}

foreach ($used as $deleteMe)
    unset($myArray[$deleteMe]);

$newArray = array_values($myArray);

var_dump($newArray);
```

It works, and creating a new array with array_values eliminates the gaps created by using unset().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$i = count($myArray);
$used = array();
while ($i-- > 0)
    if (!isset($used[$myArray[$i][1]])) {
        $used[$myArray[$i][1]] = true;
        unset($myArray[$i]);
    }
```

This simple snippet first iterates from the back over the array and deletes the index if an entry with this number wasn't deleted yet.

Comment: Wouldn't this delete the first of each kind? Since you started at the end and went to the start, the last index written in used[bla] is the first one each time.

Comment: Either way thanks. I was able to adapt your code into a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through `$myArray`, save last position of every kind in `$otherArray`, loop through `$otherArray` unseting items from `$myArray`. That's all.